# How can I make a dependency property of a list of strings in WPF?

Tags: wpf, dependency-properties

I have found some examples, but none seemed to work. I`m trying to bind a list of strings to my user control through this dependency property.

```
public IList ImageNames
    {
        get { return (IList)GetValue(ImageNamesProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ImageNamesProperty, value); }
    }

// Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for ImageNames.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
public static readonly DependencyProperty ImageNamesProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("ImageNames", typeof(IList), typeof(DynamicWallpaperUserControl), new PropertyMetadata(new List<string>()));
```

From the ViewModel, I have a List String DesertImages which I`m binding to the user control. In Xaml:

```
 <controls:DynamicWallpaperUserControl
           Background="Transparent"
           ImageNames="{Binding Path=DesertImages}" />
```

Visual Studio says the list is empty though Appreciate any help

Comment: Is the definition of DesertImages a public property?
Also, try replacing IList with List<string>.

Comment: yes, it is public

Comment: I tried List<string> as well, but no success

Comment: please show a [mcve]. given implemetation is incomplete

Comment: Add this to your UserControl constructor:
(this.Content as FrameworkElement).DataContext = this;

Comment: As a note, `new List<string>()` is not a valid default value for your dependency property, because it would be shared by all instances of your control. The default value must not be anything else but null.

Comment: Please also tell us what it exactly means when "Visual Studio says the list is empty".